# Do I need to cover non-plated mounting holes before applying a conformal coating?

Tags: mounting-holes

In reference to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/115965/should-mounting-holes-be-plated) and specifically [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/444572/47070), should we consider the same criteria if we need to apply conformal coating on the PCBs?

Do I need to cover the (non-plated or non-metalized) mounting holes with Kapton tape before to applying the conformal coating? Is it necessary?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. The holes are too big to hold a film across them. You may want to though so the screw doesn't chew up the film but you probably should not be torquing down on the PCB to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: Depending on the thickness of the coating you might find that your mounting screws don't fit in their holes as easily as they should.

Comment: Thank you, the think is that the holes are bigger that the screw and hasn't any problem to apply the screws. but per our experience we apply coating if the holes are non metalized. so the intention is standarize the conformal coating application.